# Look at assembly of function

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to look at the assembly code equivalent of a specific solidity function the compiler creates? What's the easiest way to do so during development?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `Remix` IDE for smart contract development.

1) In `Remix` IDE deploy the smart contract.

2) Execute the function of deployed smart contract.

3) Debug the function that you have executed.

4) See the `instructions` for that function.

[image]